# imakeidx \index expands macros; makeindex rejects everything

Tags: imakeidx, makeindex

I have the following minimal(ish) example. This is for a technical book with lots of code samples and lots of code-keywords-appearing-in-running-text. So I have the following goals:

- A macro `\code{foo}` for typesetting code-keywords-in-running-text. I use the `listings` package for typesetting code throughout. I also use the `underscore` package so I don't have to escape underscores in code.
- I use the `hyperref` package for cross-references, plus plenty of code keywords appearing in section titles; so I use `\texorpdfstring` in the definition of `\code`.
- Two indices: a main "Index" for English words and concepts, and a second "Index of code samples". I have heard that the `imakeidx` package is the most standard choice for this, so I'm using it. I'm open to alternatives if they can fix my problem.
- Many, complicated, index terms. Some terms must be typeset with `\code{foo}`. Some must be secondary entries, as in, "`iterator`, `std::vector::`: see `vector::iterator`."

---

### mce.tex

```
\documentclass[ebook,10pt,oneside,final]{memoir}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=mce,intoc,columns=2]
\makeindex[name=code,intoc,columns=2,name=code,title=Index of code samples]

\usepackage[final]{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{underscore}

\newcommand{\code}[1]{\texorpdfstring{\mbox{\lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily]`#1`}}{#1}}

\newcommand{\codeblockdefines}[1]{\index[code]{#1@\code{#1}}}  % for example, \codeblockdefines{list_of_int}
\newcommand{\codeindex}[1]{\index{#1@\code{#1}}}  % for example, \codeindex{const_iterator}
\newcommand{\codeindexstd}[1]{\index{namespace std@\code{namespace std}!#1@\code{#1}}}  % for example, \codeindexstd{vector}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

Here's an example of using \code{std::vector}.
\codeindexstd{vector}
\codeindex{std::vector}
\codeblockdefines{vector}

\index{std@\code{std}|see {namespace std@\code{namespace std}}}

\printindex[mce]
\printindex[code]

\end{document}
```

---

The problem I'm seeing is that `\code` and maybe some other macros are getting expanded in the .idx files. When I cat these files I see this:

### mce.idx

```
\indexentry{namespace std@\unhbox \voidb@x \hbox {\lstinline [basicstyle=\ttfamily  ]`namespace std`}!vector@\unhbox \voidb@x \hbox {\lstinline [basicstyle=\ttfamily  ]`vector`}|hyperpage}{1}
\indexentry{std::vector@\unhbox \voidb@x \hbox {\lstinline [basicstyle=\ttfamily  ]`std::vector`}|hyperpage}{1}
\indexentry{std@\code{std}|hyperindexformat{\see {namespace std@\code{namespace std}}}}{1}
```

### code.idx

```
\indexentry{vector@\unhbox \voidb@x \hbox {\lstinline [basicstyle=\ttfamily  ]`vector`}|hyperpage}{1}
```

---

How can I make `\index` and the rest of my convenience macros (`\codeblockdefines`, `\codeindex`, `\codeindexstd`) do what I want?

Comment: First move the call to `imakeidx` before loading `hyperref`.

Comment: @egreg: Okay, done. The output doesn't change, though. (EDIT: ok, the .idx files change a bit, but not significantly enough to not-be-rejected.)

Comment: I should add that I also see only one "Index" in my final .pdf file, but I *think* that's just a side-effect of having had all the entries in the "Index of code samples" be rejected. I think TeX refuses to create a page for an index if it'd have zero entries in it.

Comment: Your commands `\codeindex` and `\codeindexstd` point to a non existent index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`imakeidx` should be loaded *before* `hyperref`. However, your `\code` command is *very* fragile as it uses `\lstinline` and should be “robusted”.

```
\documentclass[ebook,10pt,oneside,final]{memoir}

\usepackage[final]{listings}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeindex[name=mce,intoc,columns=2]
\makeindex[name=code,intoc,columns=2,name=code,title=Index of code samples]

\newrobustcmd{\code}[1]{\texorpdfstring{\mbox{\lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily]{#1}}}{#1}}

\newcommand{\codeblockdefines}[1]{\index[code]{#1@\code{#1}}}  % for example, \codeblockdefines{list_of_int}
\newcommand{\codeindex}[1]{\index[mce]{#1@\code{#1}}}  % for example, \codeindex{const_iterator}
\newcommand{\codeindexstd}[1]{\index[mce]{namespace std@\code{namespace std}!#1@\code{#1}}}  % for example, \codeindexstd{vector}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

Here's an example of using \code{std::vector}.
\codeindexstd{vector}
\codeindex{std::vector}
\codeblockdefines{vector}

\index{std@\code{std}|see {namespace std@\code{namespace std}}}

\printindex[mce]
\printindex[code]

\end{document}
```

I changed the `\codeindex` and `\codeindexstd` commands to point to a defined index.

The `code.idx` file will contain

```
\indexentry{vector@\code {vector}|hyperpage}{1}
```

whereas `mce.idx` contains

```
\indexentry{namespace std@\code {namespace std}!vector@\code {vector}|hyperpage}{1}
\indexentry{std::vector@\code {std::vector}|hyperpage}{1}
```

These entries are not rejected.

Comment: Re "to point to a defined index" — My understanding was that "mce" would be the name of the main index for "mce.tex", so I didn't need to specify that name explicitly; i.e. I could write `\index{foo}` instead of `\index[mce]{foo}`. Is this wrong and/or too clever? Should I just define a convenience macro `\newcommand{\idx}[1]{\index[mce]{#1}}` and avoid using raw `\index`?

Comment: @Quuxplusone No, the unadorned `\index` command only refers to one not passed the `name` option. Just remove `name=mce`, if you want to use `\index{...}` for pointing to it.

Comment: I'll look into the `etoolbox` package. Does it *require* the change you made to use curly braces instead of backticks? My code samples use a *lot* of curly braces...

Comment: @Quuxplusone You *can* use backquotes, but they do nothing more than braces, because the argument is already tokenized. `\newrobustcmd` is just more efficient than `\DeclareRobustCommand`.

Comment: Awesome, it seems to work! (Although robustifying the whole `\code` macro broke `\texorpdfstring`, so what I did was I pulled out `\newrobustcmd{\codeinternal}[1]{\mbox{\lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily]\`#1\`}}` and then `\newcommand{\code}[1]{\texorpdfstring{\codeinternal{#1}}{#1}}`.) I'm still getting "Improper alphabetic constant" for the index entry `\indexentry{list_of_ints!::iterator@\code {list_of_ints!::iterator}}{13}`, and none of my "X, see Y" entries are showing up; but I'm sure those are unrelated issues and I'll ask new questions if I can't figure them out.